# clear content of dynamic ranges in multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to delete all data from the worksheets except for one called datainput.
I have a template for my worksheets so my data starts on row 32 (A32) but each worksheet has a different number of records.

I'm pretty new to macros and below is my miserable attempt.

Thanks,

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Integer

ws = Application.Sheets.Count

For x = 1 To ws
      If Worksheets(x).Name <> "Datainput" 
Then Worksheets(x).Rows((32),Cells(Rows.Count,Columns.Count)).ClearContents
End
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give this a try....

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long, lc As Long

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name <> "Datainput" Then
        lr = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        lc = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
        If lr > 31 Then ws.Range("A32", ws.Cells(lr, lc)).ClearContents
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```